# How to change all words to upper-case but exclude Roman numerals?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to fix some manually typed addresses. I need to apply [`ucwords`](http://php.net/ucwords) on the whole address but I want to keep all the roman numerals in uppercase and the letters after the house number.

```
VIA PIPPO III 74A
```

should become:

```
Via Pippo III 74A
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To selectively uppercase parts of a string via [`mb_eregi_replace()`](http://php.net/mb_eregi_replace):

```
$str = mb_eregi_replace('\b([0-9]{1,4}[a-z]{1,2})\b', "strtoupper('\\1')", $str, 'e');
```

Full example, how to fix an address manually typed, uppercasing the first letter of a words and keeping uppercase roman numerals and the letters A,B,C after the house number):

```
function ucAddress($str) {

    // first lowercase all and use the default ucwords
    $str = ucwords(strtolower($str));

    // let's fix the default ucwords...
    // uppercase letters after house number (was lowercased by the strtolower above)
    $str = mb_eregi_replace('\b([0-9]{1,4}[a-z]{1,2})\b', "strtoupper('\\1')", $str, 'e');

    // the same for roman numerals
    $str = mb_eregi_replace('\bM{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b', "strtoupper('\\0')", $str, 'e');

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: I've removed the advertising from the end of this answer. If you have your own website which you want to show off, please add it to your StackOverflow bio.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find words that are *not* Roman numerals:

```
/\b(?![LXIVCDM]+\b)([A-Z]+)\b/
```

Explanation:

- `\b` - assert position at a word boundary
- `(?!` - negative lookahead

  - `[LXIVCDM]+` - match any character from the list one or more times
  - `\b` - assert position at a word boundary
- `)` - end of negative lookahead
- `[A-Z]` - any uppercase alphabet, one or more times
- `\b` - assert position at a word boundary

Effectively, this matches any word that aren't *entirely* composed of the characters in the list `[LXIVCDM]` - that is, it matches any word that is not a Roman numeral.

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kD6zN8)

---

Now, use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to capture these words, convert them into lower case, and then capitalize the first letter:

```
$input = 'VIA PIPPO III 74A';    
$pattern = '/\b(?![LXIVCDM]+\b)([A-Z]+)\b/';

$output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
    return ucfirst(strtolower($matches[0]));
}, $input);

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
string(17) "Via Pippo III 74A"
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/97534)

Comment: +1 `preg_replace_callback` is indeed the right way of doing this.